flutter doctor - unable to locate android sdk on ubuntu
Running flutter doctor -v on my ubuntu 24.04.1 installation reports these problems

Unable to locate Android SDK
No valid Android SDK platforms found in /usr/local/android-sdk/platforms. Directory was empty.
Unable to determine Android Studio version

What did i try
Running ./sdkmanager --list_installed returned
$ cd /usr/local/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
$ ./sdkmanager --list_installed
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Installed packages:
  Path           | Version | Description                       | Location      
  -------        | ------- | -------                           | -------       
  platform-tools | 35.0.2  | Android SDK Platform-Tools 35.0.2 | platform-tools


So i ran also
$ cd /usr/local/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
$ sudo ./sdkmanager "emulator"
$ sudo ./sdkmanager "build-tools;35.0.0"
$ sudo ./sdkmanager "cmdline-tools;latest"

Now ./sdkmanager --list_installed returns
/usr/local/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin$ ./sdkmanager --list_installed
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Installed packages:
Path              | Version | Description        | Location            
-------           | ------- | -------            | -------             
build-tools;35.0.0| 35.0.0  | SDK Build-Tools 35 | build-tools/35.0.0  
cmdline-tools;latest| 16.0  | SDK Command-line Tools | cmdline-tools/latest
emulator          | 35.2.10 | Emulator           | emulator            
platform-tools    | 35.0.2  | SDK Platform-Tools 35.0.2 | platform-tools      

The last lines of my ~/.bashrc are
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Running tree -dL 2 /usr/local/android-sdk returns
/usr/local/android-sdk
├── build-tools
│   └── 35.0.0
├── cmdline-tools
│   └── latest
├── emulator
│   ├── bin64
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── lib64
│   ├── qemu
│   └── resources
├── licenses
└── platform-tools
    └── lib64


Still the same problem
This is the output of flutter doctor -v
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    • Android SDK at /usr/local/android-sdk
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/to/linux-android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

    • ANDROID_HOME = /usr/local/android-sdk
    ✗ No valid Android SDK platforms found in /usr/local/android-sdk/platforms. Directory was empty.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/to/linux-android-setup for detailed instructions.


[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)

Question
What else can i do to fix

Unable to locate Android SDK
No valid Android SDK platforms found in /usr/local/android-sdk/platforms


In flutter issue #11252 it is mentioned that one requirement libncurses5 is no longer available on [tag:ubuntu] 24; which i use. Does anyone know if this relevant for my problem above?

In github issue #11252 was an update: libncurses5 is likely no longer needed. They will test this and if ok will update the guide.
